# Could multiple consecutive setTimeout and clearTimeout lead to CPU peaks or memory leaks

Tags: javascript, browser, web-component

I am writing a JS web component that could lead to multiple consecutive setTimeouts and clearTimeouts depending on the end user's behavior. E.g:

```
setTimeout with returned timeoutId: 19
setTimeout with returned timeoutId: 20
setTimeout with returned timeoutId: 21
clearTimeout with timeoutId: 19
clearTimeout with timeoutId: 20
clearTimeout with timeoutId: 21
...
```

Generally speaking, could that produce CPU peaks or memory leaks?

**Note:** I am not worried about flooding the message queue with setTimeout callbacks. Also, using setInterval instead of setTimeout will not be a feasible solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It will depend on the CPU usage of the callback and the frequency of the calls

Comment: it also depends on if you remember to set your variables to `null` when you are finished with them. `Closures` can leak memory unless you force the variables to null to guarantee letting the GC run and remove the data.

Comment: @Supersharp, Intervalia: Thank you for the valuable feedback! You are both right. However, I am more concerned about the frequent communication between the JS run-time and the Web API and what happens inside the Web API itself. The later I believe is responsible for the execution and invalidation of the setTimeouts.